# Prepend static string to multiple array elements

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have two arrays:

```
$delete = array("Delete" => "Delete");

$folders = array("0" => "folder1","1" => "folder2");

$options = array_merge($delete, $folders);
```

How do I add "Move to " to $folders and have $options stay as an array?

In a drop down menu this will appear as:

```
Delete

Move to folder1

Move to folder2
```

Comment: The question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the "Move to" string to every element of the $folder array, try this:

```
$folders = array("0" => "folder1","1" => "folder2");
foreach($folders as $key => $value) {
    $folders[$key] = 'Move to '.$value;
}
$options = array_merge($delete, $folders);
```

OR (based on the suggestion of @zamnuts)

```
$folders = array("0" => "folder1","1" => "folder2");

function moveto($n) {  
     return 'Move to '.$n; 
}
$folders = array_map("moveto", $folders);
$options = array_merge($delete, $folders);
```

Comment: consider `array_map` instead of `foreach`. `array_map` helps hint that you are mutating values (and it is generally faster).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write a looping technique.  [`substr_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) will happily receive an array of strings to modify.  Arguments 3 and 4 must be set to 0.  This indicates that you want to insert your new text from the first offset/position in the string, and you do not want to replace any of the original characters when applying the new string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RsDtf))

```
$delete = array("Delete" => "Delete");

$folders = array("0" => "folder1","1" => "folder2");

$options = array_merge($delete, substr_replace($folders, 'Move to ', 0, 0));

var_export($options);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Delete' => 'Delete',
  0 => 'Move to folder1',
  1 => 'Move to folder2',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do what you need:

```
$folders[] = "Move to";

$options = array_merge($delete, $folders);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if real question, but just add it after the `array_merge()` call with `$folders[] = "Move to"`. Since `array_merge()` generates a new array, any modifications to `$delete` or `$folders` after it will not affect the content of `$options`.